# Looking to create weighted average of partitioned columns in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

Horrible title, but I couldn't find a way to describe what I'm trying to do concisely.  This question was posed to me by a friend, and I'm usually competent in Excel, but in this case I am totally stumped.

Suppose I have the following data:

```
    |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |  0.50 |  0.50 |   1   |       |       |  0.30 |  0.30 |       |
2   |  0.25 |  0.75 |   2   |       |       |  0.40 |  0.70 |       |
3   |  1.00 |  1.75 |   8   |       |       |  0.30 |  1.00 |       |
4   |  0.75 |  2.50 |   2   |       |       |  0.50 |  1.50 |       |
5   |  1.25 |  3.75 |   3   |       |       |  1.75 |  3.25 |       |
6   |  0.50 |  4.25 |   1   |       |       |  0.25 |  3.50 |       |
7   |  1.00 |  5.25 |   0   |       |       |  0.50 |  4.00 |       |
8   |  0.25 |  5.50 |   2   |       |       |  0.30 |  4.30 |       |
9   |  0.25 |  5.75 |   9   |       |       |  0.25 |  4.55 |       |
10  |  0.75 |  6.50 |   4   |       |       |  0.70 |  5.25 |       |
11  |       |       |       |       |       |  1.00 |  6.25 |       |
12  |       |       |       |       |       |  0.25 |  0.25 |       |
```

Column A represents the distance traveled while the measurement in column C was collected.  Column B represents the total distance traveled so far.  So C1 represents some value produced during the process from distance 0 to 0.5.  B2 represents the value from distance 0.5 to 0.75, and B3 represents the value from 0.75 to 1.75, etc...

Column F represents a PLANNED second iteration of the same process, but with different measurement intervals.  What I need is a way to PREDICT column H, based on a WEIGHTED AVERAGE of values from column C, based on where the intervals in column F intersect with the intervals in column A.  For example, since F2 represents the measurement taken from distance 0.30 to 0.70 (an interval of 0.4, split 50/50 across the measurements in C1 and C2), H2 would be equal to: C1*0.5 + C2*0.5: 1.5.

Another example:  H3 represents the expected measurement from an interval between 0.7 and 1.0, which is split between C2 (from 0.7 to 0.75 = 0.05) and C3 (from 0.75 to 1.0 = 0.25).  So H3 = 16.6%*C2 + 83.3%*C3 = 0.332+6.664 = 6.996.

I'm looking for a way to do this in an Excel spreadsheet without using VBA or breaking it down into something like a Python script to process externally, but so far I'm not finding any way to do it.

Any ideas for accomplishing this entirely within Excel without any special add-ins/scripts installed ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but I think the following should work for all except H1 (which would need an added zero row):

```
=(MAX(0,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G2,B:B,1))-G1)*INDEX(C:C,MATCH(G2,B:B,1)) +
  (G2-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G2,B:B,1)))*INDEX(C:C,MATCH(G2,B:B,1)+1)) / 
  MAX(G2-G1,G2-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(G2,B:B,1)))
```

It matches the values in B and C and weights them accordingly.